# Unix 'sed' command in a loop

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I would like to write a script with `sed` command as I guess this is most suitable command for my goal. 
There is a file called `NAME` which consists of different names ordered in columns like:

```
STEVE
JOHN
CLARE
```

The script should do:

1. Get `$value` from `NAME` file
2. Replace `$value` with the constant value ('ARNOLD') by `sed 's/"'$i'"/ARNOLD/g' test1.log>test2.log` (test1 and test2 files are identical).

I prepared my version of script but it worked only for the latest value in the list of names:

```
while read i; do sed 's/'"$i"'/ARNOLD/g' test1.log >test2.log ; done<name
```

Comment: So you want to replace all names with arnold ?

Comment: @User112638726 No, just the names STEVE, JOHN and CLARE. Any other names in test1.log he wants unchanged.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I meant that. So all names in NAME replace with ARNOLD.

Comment: @User112638726, yes you are  right. Only names in NAME file are supposed to be replaced with ARNOLD

Comment: Every time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. Google it. Post some TESTABLE truly representative sample input and expected output (contents of test1.log and desired contents of test2.log after the script runs) so we can help you. It's always easy to replace the text you do want replaced but MUCH harder to not affect text that you don't want to be affected.

Comment: I hope NAME doesn't has a substring of ARNOLD (like OLD)

Comment: @WalterA Yes, it does not have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might be what you need:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{names[$0];next} {for (name in names) gsub(name,"ARNOLD")}' NAME test1.log >test2.log
```

but without sample input and expected output it's a guess and it has the same potential problem with non-anchoring that all of the sed scripts posted so far have in that it'd, for example, change "JOHNSON" to "ARNOLDSON". WIth GNU awk you can solve that with word boundaries:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{names[$0];next} {for (name in names) gsub("\\<"name"\\>","ARNOLD")}' NAME test1.log >test2.log
```

but there may be other issues that we won't know be able to help you with until we see your sample input and expected output.

wrt using awk vs shell+sed (moved from a comment):

Every time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716 for one discussion on the subject. Essentially though - UNIX shell is an environment from which to call UNIX tools with a language to sequence those calls. Awk is the tool created by the same guys who invented shell to do text processing for UNIX. So, just use it. In shell you can write scripts that LOOK like they'll do the job but it's actually incredibly difficult to get the shell syntax right to robustly do text manipulation since that's not what it's designed to do (eg. `while read i` is NOT how to read input in shell - you need `while IFS= read -r i` at least) and even if you manage to get the syntax right it's immensely slow compared to awk.

If you're going to be doing ANY text manipulation in UNIX you should get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins or you're going to be wasting a lot of time creating complicated, inefficient, buggy, unmaintainable and otherwise generally awful shell scripts.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, unfortunately I'm not good at awk language. I'm a bit perplexed by variable used inside : what is the $name, $names?

Comment: Just learn how to do the job right in awk instead of learning how to do it wrong in shell+sed. `names` is an array indexed by the contents of the file `NAME`. `for (name in names)` is a loop setting a variable `name` to each index of `names`. You don't put `$` in front of variable names in awk to access their value, just like you don't in C. awk is NOT shell.

Comment: thank you for sharing information about shell's weakness while using 'while loop', I was not aware about it before. As far as awk is concerned, I started awk studying to understand your 'problem resolution' completely..

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to generate the changes and then use the output from the first as a script for another sed to read

```
sed 's/.*/s\/&\/ARNOLD\/g/' NAME | sed -f- test1.log >test2.log
```

---

#### Explanation

```
sed 's/.*/s\/&\/ARNOLD\/g/'
```

Creates

```
s/STEVE/ARNOLD/g
s/JOHN/ARNOLD/g
s/CLARE/ARNOLD/g
```

which is then piped to

```
sed -f-
```

`-f` reads a script file
`-` is standard in from the pipe

Comment: Unfortunately, it threw error: sed 's/.*/s\/&\/ARNOLD\/g/' name | sed -f- test1.log>test2.log
Cannot open pattern-file: -

Answer (score 0):

Every time your script loops, it starts with the unmodified `test1.log` and changes one name. That means that only the last name changed will appear in `test2.log`.

Each loop un-does all prior changes.

Comment: That's the problem, but you haven't provided a solution.

Comment: @chepner the OP didn't ask for a solution, and I'm not all that fond of giving people fish especially when they'd not asked for one. Quoth the OP "I would like to write a script…" which is different than "gimme a script".

Answer (score 0):

When you made a copy from your original test1.log, you can overwrite test1.log.
You could use `sed -i` or

```
sed 's/'"$i"'/ARNOLD/g' test1.log >test2.log && mv test2.log test1.log
```

This solution requires a lot of I/O and is worse than @Ed's solution.
I just added it to show how the problem @msw noticed could be fixed.